# Determine tag that contributes most to a count of likes, when tags always exist in combinations

Tags: count-data, ranking, confounding, importance, valuation

I have a dataset of `[tags, like_count]`:

```
TAGS: ["car", "travel", "adventure", "lifeontheroad", "photographer"]     LIKES: 21
TAGS: ["coffee", "travelgram", "home"]                                    LIKES: 10
TAGS: ["lanscape", "wild", "nature", "landscapephotography"]              LIKES: 13
```

The dataset is quite big. How do I find which tag is the most valuable (bring more likes)? I am interested in theory and practical examples / algorithms too.

Comment: group by tags, count likes and sort by counts -- basic SQL (or whaetver you use) query...

Comment: not so easy, there is one count assigned to a group...

I need to find the individual tag contribution by having a count for the entire group

Comment: Split your tags into component and assign the count to each component and then do your count. So from the above you'd have car:21, travel:21...etc. This will cross reference with other cases where that hashtag has been used.

Comment: I have tried that, but the results are not exact because different tags have different weight, I was thinking there should be another solution.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a coding question, or otherwise off topic. The accepted answer serves as an existence proof that meaningful statistical information can be provided in response to this question. I'm voting to leave open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you conceive of the number of likes as being related to a weighted combination of the tags.

One of the simplest such models associates a number (the "weight") $\beta_i$ to tag $i$.  When tag $i$ appears in the list of tags for an observation in the dataset, it contributes its weight $\beta_i$ to a sum, $\lambda$.  For technical reasons--as well as experience with how data like this behave--it is conventional to suppose the expected number of likes equals the exponential of $\lambda$.  If the voting for the observations is independent, the actual number of likes will have a Poisson distribution.  Your objective is to estimate the weights from the data.  This is done with a [generalized linear model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generalized-linear-model) (aka "GLM").  It is usually fit by choosing estimates $\hat\beta_i$ that maximize the likelihood of the model.  The "most valuable" tags will be those with the greatest weights, which are likely to be found among those with the greatest estimated weights.

As an example, while I was writing the preceding paragraph I fit such a model for a synthetic dataset of over 90,000 records with 676 distinct tags.  I created this dataset by specifying the $\beta$ and generating the numbers of likes according to the model.  On average there were five tags and 15 likes per observation.  The computation took three minutes.  The results indicate that almost all the coefficients $\hat\beta_i$ are significantly nonzero.  The correlation between the actual $\beta_i$ and their estimates is excellent, as the scatterplot attests.

[image: Figure]

The actual coding is almost trivial.  Here are the `R` commands to fit the model and display its results:

```R
model <- glm(Y ~ ., data=X, family=poisson)
summary(model)
```

To learn more, research ["GLM"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=GLM) and [Poisson generalized linear models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=GLM%20poisson) on this site and/or experiment with the full `R` code below.  It is likely you will want to investigate ["interactions"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+interaction+poisson) among the tags before you are fully satisfied with the model.

---

```R
#
# Create tags data.
# `X` has one column per tag to indicate its presence (1) or absence (0).
# It has one more column `Y` giving the count of likes.
#
n.obs <- 1e5 # Maximum number of observations (some will be omitted)
tags <- apply(as.matrix(expand.grid(letters, letters)), 1, paste0, collapse="")
n.tags <- length(tags)
tag.frequencies <- runif(n.tags, 0, min(1, 5/n.tags))
X <- data.frame(t(matrix(rbinom(n.obs * n.tags, 1, tag.frequencies), n.tags)))
names(X) <- tags
X <- X[rowSums(X) > 0, ]
#plot(tag.frequencies, colMeans(X)) # Check correctness
#
# Create responses.
# `beta` is the vector of tag weights.  They are allowed to be negative!
#
beta <- rbeta(n.tags, 1, 3) * 2.5 - 0.5
beta.0 <- 2
X$Y <- as.matrix(X) %*% beta + beta.0
X$Y <- rpois(nrow(X), exp(X$Y))
hist(log10(X$Y)) # Show the distribution of likes
#
# Fit a model.
#
model <- glm(Y ~ ., data=X, family=poisson)
summary(model)
#
# Compare its estimates to the true values of `beta`.
#
plot(c(beta.0, beta), coef(model), xlab="Beta", ylab="Estimated Beta")
#
# List the most valuable tags and their weights.
# NB: the list may include the intercept.  Its value merely reflects the 
# typical number of likes.
#
i <- order(coef(model))
(coef(model))[tail(i)]
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! It will take some time for me to consume your answer... :)

Comment: You're welcome.  I recommend you not accept the answer so quickly--it can discourage others from posting useful (and even better) answers.  It's usually worth waiting a day or two to see what other advice you might get.

Comment: I would also see into (multiple) correspondence analysis.